# Format('%7.8f', [varFloat]) formatting only decimals

Tags: delphi, string-formatting

Format('%7.8f', [varFloat]) formatting only decimals.

For example 13,98 becomes 13,98000000.
What I have to use is :
00000013,98000000

I know it is a dull question, but I am running short of time and I can not find why is not working as I would like.

Comment: While Pos(','string) <> 9 prepend '0' to the string

Comment: You want 18 positions where the first is blank if positive number?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. What are output are you expecting? Do you want leading zeroes for the whole part or do you not want the extraneous zeroes after the decimal point?

Comment: `FormatFloat('0000000.00000000', 13.98))`

Comment: @Andy: I wanted to add leading zeros to left.

Comment: @user246408, that should be an answer!

Comment: @TLama - no question was asked

Comment: The while loop is weak. Use N-Length() to determine how much padding is needed and pass that to StringOfChar.

Comment: @David: I used formatfloat.

Comment: Not according to your edit to the question. I reverted that anyway. Answers should not appear in questions.

Comment: I just wanted to change :) 10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are prepared to reach into the system C runtime you can use `sprintf`. For example:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

function sprintf(buf: Pointer; format: PAnsiChar): Integer; cdecl; 
  varargs; external 'msvcrt.dll';

var
  buf: array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
  val: Double;

begin
  val := 13.98;
  sprintf(@buf, '%015.8f', val);
  Writeln(buf);
  Readln;
end.
```

This outputs:

```
000013.98000000
```

You might contemplate choosing a variant that protects against buffer overruns.

But [`FormatFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatFloat) would be easier.

Comment: @Vladds It would be better if you wrote an answer based on `FormatFloat()` and accepted that. This answer is a curio. Nothing more.

Comment: FWIW, I recently used sprintf from Delphi to avoid the heap allocations that cannot be avoided with IntToStr. It saddened me to learn that the Delphi RTL cannot convert int to string using a caller supplied buffer.

Comment: In a way it is possible with `System.Str(n,aShortString);`.

Comment: A loop(n) to 10.000.000 with `Str(n,aShortString);` vs `sprintf(@buf, '%d', n);` gives 437 vs 2224 ms in x32 mode.

Comment: @LURD Interesting. I need Int64 mind you. Don't know if Str will do that. I suspect further perf. gains will be limited. Big thing is to avoid the heap.

Comment: Str does Int64 on ShortString. Still more than twice as fast as sprintf.

Comment: @LURD Thanks. I'll dig deeper tomorrow.

Comment: @LURD In the end I rolled my own using the same DivMod approach that Str uses. Hence my question today. I did it myself to avoid having to use ShortString. Did lots of unit testing. Some interesting corner cases. Particularly abs(val) where val is low(integer) and overflow/range checks are active. Was able to test all 32 bit values against IntToStr. Not possible for 64 bit int. Thanks for the idea!!

Comment: David, by using a DIVMOD with base 100 and a small LUT, I was able to make a Str procedure 2.5 times faster than System.Str on X64 and 33% faster on X32. All purepascal.

Comment: @LURD Did you use a fast DIVMOD based on multiply and bit shift? Your version sounds a little like the implementation of `IntToStr`. I think that is efficient, but it requires use of the heap.

Comment: I'm looking at J...'s answer and his way to make a better DIVMOD, more to come later with that. Yes the IntToStr resembles my Str implementation, but uses no heap.